# How to view all nodes along with all their relationships in AGE Viewer?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have a graph for cities with 6 cities, and only two of them have a relationship between them. I would like to write a query that gives me all the cities along with all the relationships in between them.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

The query above only gives me the nodes and not the relationships.
If I would like to have all the nodes along with all the relationships, what query may I use?
[image: The query only outputs the nodes]

[image: I do have relationships as well]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the below query

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
RETURN n, r
```

here "-[r]-()" matches all the relationships in the graph.

let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RIGHT JOIN clause, just like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('cities', $$ 
    MATCH (V)-[R]-(U) 
    RETURN V,R,U $$) AS g1(V agtype, R agtype, U agtype)
    RIGHT JOIN cypher('cities', $$
    MATCH (V) 
    RETURN V $$) AS g2(V agtype) 
    ON g1.V= g2.V;
```

In your case, it will show you this:
[image: a graph with all nodes, including those that have no relationship]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Cypher query language for data retrieval from the graph. The following query will return all nodes and their relationship ships

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
RETURN n, r, m
```

Basically, nodes (n) having relationships (r) with other nodes (m) will be returned.